# store value from button in variable using javaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have two buttons and I want to store the value attribute of the button pressed into a variable called amount. The code below is clearly wrong I have two identical id's for both buttons. What should I be doing in the function to save the value attribute to the variable amount onclick?

```
<button type="button" id='btn' onclick='storeVar' value='1'>1</button>
<button type="button" id='btn' onclick='storeVar' value='2'>2</button>
<script>
  function storeVar() {
    var amount = document.getElementById('btn').getAttribute('value');
    console.log(amount);
  } 
</script>
```

Comment: `I have two identical id's for both buttons` That is invalid HTML. Fix that first. You also need to invoke the functions properly in the attribute, or, even better, attach the listeners properly using Javascript instead.

Comment: They should not have the same value for attribute `id`

Answer (score 4):

The attribute *id* must be unique in a document, use *class* instead. Also pass `this` to the function so that you can refer the current button inside the function:

```js
function storeVar(el) {
  var amount = el.getAttribute('value'); 
  // OR: simply 
  // var amount = el.value;
  console.log(amount);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class='btn' onclick='storeVar(this)' value='1'>1</button>
<button type="button" class='btn' onclick='storeVar(this)' value='2'>2</button>
```

Comment: Why bother with `.getAttribute('value');` why not just use `el.value`?

Comment: @NewToJS, I was trying not to change OP's code much ..... though added that as part of the answer........thanks.

Comment: Understandable but since your answer update I believe this is now a better solution. **+1**

Comment: @NewToJS, thanks for helping me to improve the answer :)

Comment: One last thing, you can no doubt remove the `class` attribute since it isn't really being used. Also, you are welcome :)

Comment: @NewToJS, you are right but I want to keep that as a reference.....thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Either give a unique id for each button or completely remove id attribute. After fixing your html try the following code.

```html
<button type="button" id='btn' onclick='storeVar(this.value)' value='1'>1</button>
<button type="button" id='btn-two' onclick='storeVar(this.value)' value='2'>2</button>

<script>
    function storeVar(v){
        let amount = v;
        console.log(amount);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to have unique Id's.

```
<button type="button" id='btn-one' onclick='storeVar(this.value)' value='1'>1</button>
<button type="button" id='btn-two' onclick='storeVar(this.value)' value='2'>2</button>

<script>
function storeVar(value){
    let amount = value;
    console.log(amount);
}
</script>
```